# how to convert the stack of image ending with (.raw) to arrays in Spyder IDE

Tags: arrays, image, plot, spyder, raw

I have a processed image for data in Fiji and I want to convert the stack image into arrays by using Python-Spyder IDE.
The characteristics of the data as follows:

Name: `IL100Acid_Segmented_29x223x730x8bit.raw`.

The `x-axis = 29` ; `y-axis = 223` ; `z-axis = 703`.
where z-axis represents time steps

Other characteristics:

The `timestep` represented for each slice is 1 second per slice.

The resolution of the image is 0.1 mm per pixel.

The fluid is represented by pixels with values of 255, and air is represented by pixels with values of 0.

I have tried to code by the following script:

```
from skimage import L100
my_image  = L100.imread("IL100Acid_29x223x730x8bi.raw")
print(my_image)
```

But the result is:

```
runfile('C:/KFUPM V-4/KFUPM/SEM 232/Introduction to Digital Rock Petrophysics/Session-5&6/HW-02/DRP-HW(2).py', wdir='C:/KFUPM V-4/KFUPM/SEM 232/Introduction to Digital Rock     Petrophysics/Session-5&6/HW-02')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\kfupm v-4\kfupm\sem 232\introduction to digital rock petrophysics\session-5&6\hw-02\drp-hw(2).py:15
image.data[:] = open('IL100Acid_29x223x730x8bi.raw').read()

NotImplementedError: memoryview slice assignments are currently restricted to ndim = 1
```

Comment: Maybe you can share your image via Google Drive, or Dropbox or similar?

Comment: If we can't see the image, it's rather difficult to assist.